# Problem with exporting a page to PDF with Python

Tags: python, pdfkit, export-to-pdf, streamlit

I have a dashboard created by streamlit package with a button at the end to export it.
[image]
This dashboard is a html page with a URL like this : 'http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX'

And I use pdfkit package to convert an html page using URL to a pdf.

It works when I try for example 'google.fr' it convert the google main page to PDF
but when I try it with my dashboard, the PDF exported is a white page ...

This is my code :

```
import pdfkit

path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_url("http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX", "dashboard.pdf", configuration=config) #white page
pdfkit.from_url("google.fr", "dashboard3.pdf", configuration=config) #works
```

Comment: did you try using `jinja2`, `pdfkit` ?

Comment: try pdfkit.from_file()